# Fluent Nhibernate exception in Parent/Child in same table?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have this error occurs when saving:

"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave."

Entities:

```
public class Division : EntityBase<int>
{
    public Division()
        : base()
    {
        DivisionType = new DivisionType();
        Employees = new List<Employee>();
        DivisionChildren = new List<Division>();
    }

    public virtual string DivisionName { get; set; }
    public virtual DivisionType DivisionType { get; set; }
    public virtual Division ParentDivision { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Division> DivisionChildren { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Mappings:

```
public class DivisionMap : ClassMap<Division>
{
    public DivisionMap()
    {
        Table("param.Division");

        Id(x => x.Id).Column("DivisionId");
        Map(x => x.DivisionName);
        References(x => x.DivisionType).Column("DivisionTypeId");
        References(x => x.ParentDivision).Column("ParentDivisionId");
        HasMany(x => x.DivisionChildren).KeyColumn("ParentDivisionId").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
        HasMany(x => x.Employees).KeyColumn("DivisionId").Inverse().Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have Divison with its parent and childs.
When I call:

```
Session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
NhUnitOfWork.Current.Commit();
```

The error exception above occurs!!

Where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor - there is new instance `DivisionType` created

```
 DivisionType = new DivisionType();
```

And the mapping does not handle its cascade anyhow:

```
References(x => x.DivisionType).Column("DivisionTypeId");
```

That is the cause of the exception. If you want to create the Type all-over-again... you can introduce the Cascade as well. But mostlikely you should bind it .. from list of existing types...

So, the not preferred solution *(just in my thinking)* would NOT be this:

```
References(x => x.DivisionType)
    .Column("DivisionTypeId");
    .Cascade.All();
```

But it will work.

The way I would suggest to go is to get the reference to existing DivisionType and assign it

```
entity.DivisionType = Session.Load<DivisionType>(typeId); // recieved from client
Session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
NhUnitOfWork.Current.Commit();
```

*NOTE: I would strongly suggest to change the initialization of your reference and collections - these are virtual properties and that means that they should not be created in constructor... convert the auto property into properties with private backing fields - to be initiated*

*see for example - [CA2214: Do not call overridable methods in constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182331.aspx)*

EXTEND: The exception says:

1. object references ...  *(this is most likely the DivisionType)*
2. an unsaved transient instance .. *(yes, the property DivisionType was created in constructor == it is transient instance)*
3. save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave.
4. Type: HR.Core.Data.Entities.Division ... *(this is the type which does have the reference)*

So, because the DivisionType **is mapped**, NHibernate does try to persist its id into column **`"DivisionTypeId"`**.

But becuase the DivisionType does not have ID - it is a transient instance - the exception is thrown.

There are no issues with Parent/Child mapping

EXTEND MORE:

So now we know, that we also in some upper layer assign the `entity.ParentDivision`. The most suitable and appropriate way how to do that would be:

```
entity.ParentDivision = session.Load<Division>(parentDivisionId);
```

If the session is not part of the service (MVC controller) layer - we can create some DAO method e.g.:

```
public virtual Division GetById(id)
{
    var session = ... // ISessionFactory gets session
    return session.Get<Division>(id);
}
```

This is really very important when working with NHibernate. If we want NHibernate to do all the cascades, the references should be coming through NHibernate (Get or Load)...

Please do read this deep explanation:

[NHibernate – The difference between Get, Load and querying by id](http://ayende.com/blog/3988/nhibernate-the-difference-between-get-load-and-querying-by-id)

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem. Because when I put a value in ParentDivisionId, the error dosen't occur, but wehen ParentDivisionId equal to zero, the entity is saved successfully. Howevern, I tried your snipped code, but it didn't work.

Comment: The exception is in the question above.

Comment: This is the full error exception:
"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing or set cascade action for the property to something that would make it autosave. Type: HR.Core.Data.Entities.Division, Entity: HR.Core.Data.Entities.Division"
No Inner Exception

Comment: I really would like to help you. But I need more information. AND 1) Look, the mapping you showed says: `References(x => x.DivisionType)`. That means, that Division Type will be persisted into the Division table as the `DivisionTypeId`. 2) If NHibernates tries to save your entity it has reference to DivisionType created in the constructor. 3) **This transient instance** - this DivsionType property is causing the exception. Please, Do you understand me, what am I trying to say? I am almost sure, that this is the issue. Because other mapping is CORRECT. the property ParentDivision including

Comment: I know what you mean, but the code you gave it to me is not working: <br/>
References(x => x.DivisionType)
    .Column("DivisionTypeId");
    .Inverse().Cascade.All();
<br/>
Are you sure that this code works?. Because .Inverse() is not even exist in References (ManyToOne relation).

Comment: *NOOO. Sorry, I missed that the Children collection was already marked as Inverse()... forget that. Not the `ParentDivision`. NO.* --- **But yes, `DivsionType` can be mapped with Cascade!**

Comment: Anyhow, what I am trying to say from the begining, this should solve the issue: `References(x => x.DivisionType).Column("DivisionTypeId").Cascade.All();` Simply follow my answer, please *(I Copy/pasted the Cascade and accidently kept the `Inverse()` - which belongs only to HasMany)*

Comment: I knew that you accidently put Inverse() in the code. So, I already tried "References(x => x.DivisionType).Column("DivisionTypeId").Cascade.All();", but the problem is same.

Comment: I deleted "ParentDivisionId" from the table and from all my classes, and from the view, after that, I pressed save on my screen. And guess what, the entity succesfully saved! that's why I told you that the problem from ParentDivisionId. But I don't know the problem is!!!

Comment: It does not make sense... because you did not assign `entity.ParentDivision = New Divsion()`... as you showed in the question... the ParentDivsion is all the time set to null... so that could not be the problem of the exception in the question. But... ok... sorry I did not help. All this case does not make sense to me... Really sorry... Bud you do not give up. NHibernate is awesome tool ;)

Comment: I forget to tell you that, entity.ParentDivision is initialized in the controller and then assign the Id to it. But, I guess that because the Id is equal to zero the exception occured!
Because when I assign Id > 0 to it the entity is successfully saved

Comment: This is the issue as well! of course. Becuase the ID == 0 means that the entity is not persisted. It really means that it is transient. But do you know what? we should not assign some Divsion... and then set the ID to it. we should use exactly this session.Get<Division>(id) or session.Load<Division>(id) and the result assing to that property. This is essential. I will try that in answer... give me sec

Comment: OK, I hope you find the solution.

Comment: You explained the idea perfectly. But, what if ParentDivisionId is nullable??

Comment: I found an interesting thing. When I put this code "References(x => x.ParentDivision).Column("ParentDivisionId").Nullable();" in mapping, and this code "if(Division.Id == 0) Division.ParentDivision = null;" in controller before saving, the entity is successfully save!